# How to pass 'using' DB to the django connection object

Tags: python, django

To query a specific database in django I can do:

```
Item.objects.using('specific_db').all()
```

Is there a way to do the same using a django connection? For example:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor=connection.using('specific_db').cursor()
```

If not, how could I get a cursor/connection for a specific DB without manually providing all the credentials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According the the django documentation on [Using raw SQL on multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-raw-cursors-with-multiple-databases), you would use `connections` rather than `connection`:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['specific_db'].cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from item")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer in a few. :) Good luck on your project.

Comment: shouldn't the connection and cursor to be closed after use for safety ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet for performing raw SQL queries

from django.db import connection

```
def connect_to_db():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Table""")
         return dict(zip([col[0] for col in cursor.description], row)) for row / 
                in cursor.fetchall()
```